# Error to bring up interface ens32

Tags: interface

I downloaded a pre configured machine for a lab tests, I am running this in Virtualbox.
This machine came with an interface *ens32* configured with ip dns etc, but I can't bring this interface up.I am not sure if it is a virtualbox error or Linux, I  was reading that the new version has problems with this kind of names of interfaces, but I tried to change and didn't work.[image]

Comment: and If  I use the command "ifconfig", doesn't show me anything, just my lo.

Comment: I found the solution, just had to change the name of mine interface..  :D